# Insert part of a file into another file at a specific location

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I am trying to copy a part of a file into another file at a specific location.

I can't use `sed -i '/match/r fileToInsert' file` because I want to insert only some content of fileToInsert, not the whole file.

My fileToInsert is as follow:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>                                                                                                                                                  
 <!-- OriginalName: test.xml -->                                                                                                                                                        
 <ListModes>
 ...
```

I tried this:

`sed -i "/match/a$(sed -n '2,3p' fileToInsert)" file`

But it does not work either because fileToInsert is an xml file and sed chokes on the second line when encountering the opening "<":

`` sed -e expression #1, char 59: unknown command: `<' ``

(it works if I try with just one line though).

Is there any way to achieve what I want on linux ? Could be with sed, awk or any other existing utility on a redhat distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`awk` can do this completely in one single command:

```bash
awk '
FNR == NR {
   if (FNR >= 2 && FNR <= 3)
      s = s $0 ORS
   next
}
1
/match/ {
   printf "%s", s
}' fileToInsert file
```

---

Showing `find + awk` solution as commented below:

```bash
cat ins.awk

FNR == NR {
   if (FNR >= 2 && FNR <= 3)
      s = s $0 ORS
   next
}
1
/match/ {
   printf "%s", s
}
```

Run it as:

```bash
find . -type f -exec awk -f ins.awk fileToInsert {} \;
```

---

**Update:** In response to this comment:

> To be totally complete, if I wanted to insert only after the first match (or for the first nth matches), how would I do that please ?

You can use:

```bash
FNR == NR {
   if (FNR >= 2 && FNR <= 3)
      s = s $0 ORS
   next
}
1
!done && /match/ {
   printf "%s", s
   ++done
}
```

Or to insert after first `MAX` matches only change last block to:

```bash
n <= MAX && /match/ {
   printf "%s", s
   ++n
}
```

Comment: It seems like it works every time, and it should be easy enough to adapt it to insert before the match I guess, I should definitely improve my awk skills !

Comment: I am happy to answer any question/query about this `awk` solution even though it is fairly basic awk.

Comment: If you want to insert before the match just move line with `1` after `/match/ { ... }` block.

Comment: If I want to apply your solution to many files at once (for instance with find and xargs), should I put it into an awk script ? With sed or awk, every time there's a need for a `{`, there is also a newline after it and I have trouble using it directly on a terminal

Comment: I have addd `find + awk` solution using awk script in my answer.

Comment: To be totally complete, if I wanted to insert only after the first match (or for the first nth matches), how would I do that please ?

Comment: I have made another update to my answer for that.

Answer (score 6):

I would try with a bash [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html)

```bash
#!/bin/bash

sed -i '/match/r '<(sed -n '2,3p' fileToInsert) file
```

Comment: This works great, but only on the first match. Is it possible to insert after every matches ? What if I wanted to insert before a pattern, would it be easy to adapt your answer ?

Comment: @PrOpoLo correct, the purpose of this construct is to insert the content or modified content of a file **after the first match**. For other use-cases you'll better off using `awk`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps less elegent, but `sed` substitutions can also run internal commands in subshells with the `e` flag.

```
$: cat 1
1
2
3
4
5

$: cat a
a
b
c
d
e
```

## edited

```
$: sed '/3/{p;s/.*/sed -n 2,3p a/e}' 1
1
2
3
b
c
4
5
```

Not sure if that feature is GNU only. I think this one is - can use an `e` command as a standalone. If you do that you need to explicitly print the original line first, then execute the subshell, *then delete* it to prevent duplicate output - which means grouping multiple commands, and this needs an *actual* newline after the `e` command instead of just a semicolon. See below.

```
$: sed '/3/{p;e sed -n 2,3p a
d}' 1
1
2
3
b
c
4
5
```

Comment: It works but it inserts before the match and not after. I guess this could be an alternative if that's what we want ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that detail on the last one. Fixed it. The substitution works as-is if I understood the goal.

Comment: It deletes the line though, I want to keep it. Also I'd like to script it to use in on many files and I can't if I need an actual newline when grouping commands. But at least your first example worked fine if I wanted to insert before the match, which does not seem possible with the 'r' command

Comment: You want to *keep* it, and insert the output *after - editing...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "2,3W file" | ed -s fileToInsert
```